# How do I create simple tabs with CSS and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create some simple tabs.

I have 3 `div`s with different content and I have positioned them on top of each other by setting a minus top-margin on the second two `div`s.

Then I have 3 tabs and I have set up my code so that when you click `#tab1 .fadein content1`.

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content-kidsclub").hide();
  $("#tab1").click(function() {
    $(".content-kidsclub").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content-computersuite").hide();
  $("#tab2").click(function() {
    $(".content-computersuite").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content-education-assistance").hide();
  $("#tab3").click(function() {
    $(".content-education-assistance").fadeTo("slow", 1.0);
  });
});
```

The first time I click each one it works well. but after that it just stops. And also: If you click tab2 first it is way above due to the minus margin. not sure why.

I feel so close yet so far. I have suspisions its something to do with callbacks.

I am very new to jQuery so this might seem a bit dumb what I am trying to do.

Overall does anyone know a better way to position `div`s on top of each other then get the tabs to work. Is it something to do with using `display:block` and all that sort of thing.

Comment: You only need one `$(document).ready()` function. You can do all of your tab stuff in one ready function.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use JQuery UI and use the tabs function?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Super easy to set up and get going.

Comment: I can provide more detailed help if you're having problems.

Answer (score 3):

You were pretty close - http://jsfiddle.net/7mfLF/1/

Note that you don't have to repeat the `document.ready` part - declare once and good to go.

Sure you can use Bootstrap and jQuery UI, but they're REALLY heavy and for these kind of small tasks it's not really the best practice to include a 130Kb library.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li").click(function() {
        $("li div").hide();
        $(this).children("div").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but could you be more specific. Do i still need the -margin and what is the li about and the this what do i change to my stuff?

Comment: I have done the tabs the way that link said but the problem is they dont look the same in live view as in preview in browser which makes designing the look of the page really hard

Comment: `$(this)` refers to the currently clicked element. And you don't need my CSS - you're free to change it according to your design.

Comment: I wouldn't consider JQuery UI to be heavy, especially when you can customize it to your needs and minify. Also if you're using the google CDN it's likely the user may have it cached. I do believe it may have been over the OP's head though and this seems a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're showing your tabs but never hiding them again?

Ever think of using the twitter bootstrap? Might simplify things...

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out finally cheers for helping this is what i wanted.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#tab1").click(function(){
        $(".content-computersuite").css({display: "none"}).animate({opacity: "0"});
        $(".content-education-assistance").css({display: "none"}).animate({opacity: "0"});                    
        $(".content-kidsclub").css({display: "block"}).animate({opacity: "1"},1000);    
    });

    $("#tab2").click(function(){
        $(".content-kidsclub").css({display: "none"}).animate({opacity: "0"});  
        $(".content-education-assistance").css({display: "none"}).animate({opacity: "0"});
        $(".content-computersuite").css({display: "block"}).animate({opacity: "1"},1000);   
    });

    $("#tab3").click(function(){
        $(".content-kidsclub").css({display: "none"}).animate({opacity: "0"});  
        $(".content-computersuite").css({display: "none"}).animate({opacity: "0"});
        $(".content-education-assistance").css({display: "block"}).animate({opacity: "1"},1000);    
    });
});
```

Just a simple CSS change from display:none to display:block. then an animate to fade it. cheers for explaining i only have to do the document ready once that was handy.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code in my projects:

[Simple Tabs w/ CSS & jQuery](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/542/Simple-Tabs-w-CSS-jQuery.html)

It is simple, lightweight because uses pure JQuery (without JQuery UI) and works in all browser that i've tested. Hope can help you.